# How to install and set up Neat in Gulp correctly?

Tags: installation, gulp, neat

Bourbon and Normalize are working, Neat don't. I tried different ways and always received a message 'no mixine named..', that is not correctly established, although I installed with the help of NPM and Bower

```
var neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;

.pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [bourbon, normalize, neat],
      outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
```

got a message:

```
Error: no mixin named span-columns
       Backtrace:
        src/style/main.sass:6
        on line 6 of src/style/main.sass
>>   @include span-columns(4);
   -----------^
```

when i write in sass file

```
+outer-container or +span-columns()
```

but i saw how they are used..

Comment: It's unclear what the question is here. Also, you should put the text of your relevant code into the body of the question. No one wants to read code from an image.

Comment: +grid-container works so Neat works too) what about outer-container and span-columns? I saw how they are used..

Comment: Don't put updates in comments; [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45678539/edit) the **body** of the question.

Comment: Are you using neat 2.0 ? They removed a lot of mixins in the new version. If yes please refer to http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/latest/ for latest documentation

Comment: Can you confirm which neat version you installed ? Those mixins ( span-columns, outer-countainer) are from previous version of neat (1.x), so you need to install older neat version if you don't want to change it.

Comment: I installed it using npm (v. 2.0.0-beta.0) and bower (v. 2.1.0). I just have to use the new syntax and mixines? omg.. thanks) I studied the old video

Comment: Yes, you will need to adopt new mixins if you use version 2. You can install the version 2.1.0 as well in npm by using npm install --save bourbon-neat@2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing versions of Neat. check your version as many of the mixins have changed or renamed. As an example, the main column mixin in 1.X is `span-columns` but in 2.X it is `grid-column`.

You can specify which version you want to use in your `package.json` file.

If you continue to have issues check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/gulp-bourbon-neat-example which is a working gulp project using bourbon and neat

- http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/2.1.0/
- http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/1.9.0/